# Show that if the arrow $f: A \to B$ is an epimorphism then the arrow $id \times f: C\times A \to C \times B$ is an epimorphism as well

Tags: category-theory

I'm following the book Sets for Mathematics by Lawvere. As an exercise in section 7 it's stated that if we have an arrow $f: A \rightarrow   B$ that is an epimorphism then the arrow $id\times f: C\times A \to  C  \times B$ is also an epimorphism. On the book it's recomended to do so by the use of exponentials. Maybe we can use the property that since $f$ is an epi then, for all $V$ it happens that the arrow $V^f: V^B \to V^A$ is injective. In particular the arrow $C^f: C^B \to C^A$, although I don't see how we could use it if in fact we could use it.

Comment: So, suppose you have two morphisms $g_1, g_2 : C \times B \to V$ which are equalized by $\operatorname{id} \times f$.  Then $g_1, g_2$ correspond to morphisms $B \to V^C$...

Comment: So then I should use the epi property of $f$ to see that for any $g_1,g_2 :  B \to V^C$ if $g_1 \circ f = g_2 \circ f$ then $g_1=g_2$? but how can I see that $g_1,g_2$ equalizing $id \times f$ implies that they also equalize $f$?

Comment: If you apply the fact that the adjunction $\operatorname{Hom}(-, V^C) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(C \times -, V)$ is a natural transformation, you will get that $g_1 \circ (\operatorname{id} \times f)$ corresponds to $g_1' \circ f$ if $g_1$ corresponds to $g_1'$.

Comment: If you know the converse of your statement about $V^f$ being mono, then you can just set $C=U^C$ for varying $U$:

Comment: I can't see how to use that that is a natural transformation to see that $g_1 \circ (id \times f)$ corresponds to $g'_1 \circ f$ because surely I have to use some property of the identity arrow of C to get the correspondence. I thought maybe some sort of iso between arrows from A to B and arrows from $Cx \times A$ to $C \times B$ of the form $id \times ( )$